# Can a wife force her husband to have sex in islam?

Tags: wife

Is it allowed for a woman to force her husband to have sex with her in islam?

Answer (score 1):

Allah said (Translation):

> And women shall have rights similar to the rights against them,
> according to what is equitable, but men have a degree (of advantage) over them.

Accordingly, fulfilling the need of each other is required and it is one of the purposes of marriage in Islam.

Yet, no one can force the other, especially if they are ill or unable to do it (e.g. the wife during the period).

Allah said (Translation):

> On the contrary live with them on a footing of kindness and equity

Nevertheless, there is an authentic hadith that if the wife does not obey her husband in bed in doing what is Halal, without any reasonable cause, such as being sick or something like the period...etc, she will be cursed by angels.
Although I don't know a similar rule if it is vice versa, a woman can ask for a divorce if the husband is sexually faulty/blameworthy, if she wills.